# Maapping template default to None if no input from user

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have one API GET method integrated with lambda, in lambda integration mapping template.

**mapping template:**

```
{
    "name" : "$input.params('name')",
    "std_out" : "$input.params('std_out')" 
}
```

condition is to set `std_out` default value to none but if user sends something in `std_out` then users values will be assign to it.
I'm not getting how to make std_out default to none but still accepts input if user pass any.
**Things that I tried:**

1. One way I think is instead of using GET, I will use POST method and will not use any mapping template. but this is not standard way.
2. I can ask User to send None if not passing any values, but still exploring if I can do something on my level to reduce the overhead from user.
   So Is there any solution using GET method.

Comment: Use a function in input so you can check the input value and you can return None if not meet the standard.

Comment: @bonifacio_kid function in input? I did not get that how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Although [VTL variables](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference.html#variables) seem to allow for an *alternate* value when empty, apparently API Gateway does not support that and fails to transform request.

The next best option is to use an inline if/else condition to perform the same:

```
## setting to a variable for readability, but not strictly necessary
#set( $std_out = $input.params('std_out') )
{
    "name" : "$input.params('name')",
    "std_out": #if( $std_out != '' )"$std_out"#{else}"None"#end
}
```

In case you want to skip passing the field if the user did not pass it, wrap the whole field inside the if/else:

```
{
## putting before 'name' so we don't have to deal with the comma there
#if( $input.params('std_out') != '' )
    "std_out": "$input.params('std_out')",
#end
    "name" : "$input.params('name')"
}
```